# Set specific TERM variable for only emacs terminals

Tags: colors, term, multi-term

I'm using `multi-term` right now in GUI cocoa emacs on OSX, and it works great in general. However, I'm running into a bit of an issue with my `TERM` variable. I generally set it to `xterm-256color` for iterm, but that causes odd behavior with terminal apps like htop in emacs `multi-term`. However, htop and other terminal apps work perfectly in `multi-term` when `TERM` is set to `eterm-color`.

As a result, I'm wondering if there is any way for me to have `xterm-256color` as the default coded in my .bash_profile, but have emacs automatically run `TERM=eterm-color` or a similar command when starting a new multi-term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminals run inside of emacs set an environment variable, `INSIDE_EMACS`, so you can test that inside of your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` to set the `TERM` to something else.

(BTW on my system, `multi-term` seems to be setting `TERM` to `eterm-color` automatically…)

Comment: hmm, interesting. I did read that `multi-term` automatically sets `TERM` to `eterm-color` but it isn't working for me. I'll use the `INSIDE_EMACS` variable instead, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @amitp's answer above, here's what I did in my .zshenv file to set my $EDITOR env variable:

```
if [[ -v INSIDE_EMACS ]]; then
    export EDITOR="emacsclient"
else
    # Regular shell
    export EDITOR="emacsclient -t"
fi
```